# Running cockroachdb on a Raspberry pi 2 model b (32-bit) as a docker container

Tags: pi-2, arm, software-compilation, database, golang

I'm trying to run cockcroachdb on a Raspberry Pi within a docker container, but they only provide 64-bit versions of cockroach as they explained it [here](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/32147#issuecomment-438055230) .

But I do see references of running cockroach on probably a 32-bit pi [as in an official blog post](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/run-cockroachdb-on-a-raspberry-pi/) but it seems dated and it doesn't work.

They have [build configurations](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/32147#issuecomment-437999721) for multiple architectures, but I'm not that familiar with go and any modification I make to the build-files don't work either.

Is there a way to compile cockroach to run on a 32-bit pi?